# Excel: how do i lookup a cell number by containing text and return it

Tags: excel, function, return, cell

my problem is the following:
I need a formula that takes a text value from column A and checks if this value is in column Q. If yes it should return the value of the associated cell in column P.

But i already fail to return the cell address of column Q if it matches.

This is my formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($Q$2:$Q$577;A222);MATCH(A222;$Q$2:$Q$577M;0);" ")
```

Comment: You can use: `=IFERROR(INDEX($P$2:$P$577;MATCH(A222;$Q$2:$Q$577M;0));"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INDEX and MATCH to get this output like Rory suggested

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($P$2:$P$577;MATCH(A222;$Q$2:$Q$577;0));"")
```

If you have O365, you can also use [Xlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) like this:

```
=XLOOKUP(A222;$Q$2:$Q$577;$P$2:$P$577)
```

Comment: For unknown reasons only the XLOOKUP answer worked. But that's enough for me, thanks guys, you saved my day.

Comment: probably because there was a unnecessary text in the INDEX formula. I updated the formula. Can you try now?

Comment: Still returns blank although it's true.

Comment: Oh, its difficult to debug the issue without looking at it. But you could use the `Xlookup` function which is more simple.